# Register Plugin inside vue custom component

Tags: vue.js

I got the definition of a custom element like:

```
const CustomElement = defineCustomElement(Panel);
window.customElements.define('custom-commentpanel', CustomElement);
```

How would I register a plugin such as Vuex to that custom element?

Answer (score 0):

Add your plugin [as shown in the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#committing-mutations-inside-plugins) and register it to your custom element like so :

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // your store options here
  plugins: [myPlugin]
});

const CustomElement = defineCustomElement(Panel, {
  store
});

window.customElements.define('custom-commentpanel', CustomElement);
```